# Q-Q plot - Why do we choose the empirical distribution $F_n(x) = \frac {\#\{y \in S \mid y \le x\}} n$, $S$ is sample, for comparison with normal?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, distributions

When using Q-Q plot, why do we choose the empirical distribution $F_n(x) = \frac {\#\{y \in S \mid y \le x\}}  n$, $S$ is sample, for comparison with normal?

Let $S$ be our sample of size $n$. Then we form the empirical distribution  $F_n$ as defined above. We then use a Q-Q plot to compare $F_n$ to $N(0,1)$ to see if there might be a linear relationship.

1. Why do we choose $F_n$ as the empirical distribution for our sample?
2. Could we get other results if we did not choose $F_n$ as the empirical distribution?
3. For the fractile of $p \in (0,1)$ we choose the midpoint $x$ of the interval corresponding to $p$. Why do we choose the midpoint?

Comment: What would you propose using to represent the distribution of the data instead of $F_n$?

Comment: I don't know. But what justify the choice ? Only that we have no other choice ?

Comment: As it stands, your question sounds like "why do we use our data in order to analyze our data?"  Do you see why that is confusing?

Comment: See my answer on math stack exchange.

Comment: The Q's stand for "quantile." We would expect the quantiles of normally-distributed data to approximately match those of the reference distribution (albeit with some error due to finite sample size). The indicator function give us the empirical quantiles for each element of the sample.

Comment: Is the emperical quantiles always determined like this ?

Comment: There are many methods for computing empirical quantiles; I will redirect this thread to one in which that question is answered (by Jeromy Anglim).